# Fermentation Temperature

Tags: fermentation, fermentation-temperature, temperature, temperature-control, primary-fermentation

I have a quick question. I've been looking for an answer, but didn't find a clear answer.

So, I'm making an IPA. Right now the air temperature in my closet where I keep the carboy is 67-68F. This is what I should have according to the yeast profile. However, the fermometer (tape on the carboy) reads at 72F. That is understandable, because yeast are doing their work like crazy, which increases the temperature of the wort...

Should I be worried? Should I move my carboy to a keezer (with temp control) and force the temperature of the wort to get down to 67-68F by lowering the environment temperature to 60-62F?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little worried, perhaps, but regardless you should attempt to keep the yeast/beer itself in the yeast's ideal temperature range. If you have a temp controller, then look into getting some sort of "thermowell" to put the temp controller's sensor in the middle of the fermentor itself, but taping (and insulting) the probe against the side of the fermentor will work fine.

What yeast are you using? Some strains like (or require) higher temps. Assuming you're using US-05/WY1056/WLP001 … it doesn't like to be underpitched or ferment much over 70°F or it will throw both fusels and diacetyl.

Comment: Yeah, I'm using WLP001... I should control the crazy yeasts. I'll remove all my kegs from keezer and do exactly as you suggested. I'll tape the temp sensor to carboy. Hopefully, one day with temperature over 70 wont produce much dactyl.  Thanks